# How to select list items in a nested list that is generated from a text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file saying

```
Mash,25.50,108.00  
Enhanced,37.50,162.00  
Pellets,30.00,135.00  
Protein Plus,39.00,174.00  
Calcium Plus,39.00,174.00
```

I run it into a print statement

```
def readfile():
    textlist = [line.split(',') for line in open("chookfood.txt", 'r')]
    print(','.join([str(lst) for lst in textlist]))

readfile()
```

It outputs this nested list:

```
['Mash', '25.50', '108.00\n'],['Enhanced', '37.50', '162.00\n'],['Pellets', '30.00', '135.00\n'],['Protein Plus', '39.00', '174.00\n'],['Calcium Plus', '39.00', '174.00']
```

How do I make a print statement to print mash[1]. I can't store these values in the python idle so I need someway to ask how print the 25.50 from mash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a list of lists with the content. You just need to return the list from the function and then access the contents with list indexing:

```
def readfile():
    textlist = [line.split(',') for line in open("test.txt", 'r')]
    return textlist

l = readfile()
print(l)
#Output:
[['Mash', '25.50', '108.00\n'],
 ['Enhanced', '37.50', '162.00\n'],
 ['Pellets', '30.00', '135.00\n'],
 ['Protein Plus', '39.00', '174.00\n'],
 ['Calcium Plus', '39.00', '174.00']]
```

Then, just use list indexing:

```
l[0][1]
#'25.50'
```

Comment: Is this stored as a nested list? how would I call Calcium plus 39.00 to say add 5?

Comment: Also when I output this I get
```
[['Mash', '25.50', '108.00\n'], ['Enhanced', '37.50', '162.00\n'], ['Pellets', '30.00', '135.00\n'], ['Protein Plus', '39.00', '174.00\n'], ['Calcium Plus', '39.00', '174.00']]
```
Will the /n affect anything?

Comment: For that situation, a dictionary will be the best choice. However, I do not get the sort of output that you get for the lists.

Comment: I get `['Mash', '25.50', '108.00 Enhanced', '37.50', '162.00 Pellets', '30.00', '135.00 Protein Plus', '39.00', '174.00 Calcium Plus', '39.00', '174.00']`

Comment: Yes, it was the newlines, I'm getting the same sort of output now.

Comment: I can now call these items. Is their anychance you know how to make a gui graph using canvas. I need to compare cost calling these items but having the ability for them to change

Comment: That's a separate question. If you have a dataset, then you should explore libraries such as pandas for viewing the data in a nice tabular format and then visualize with a library like matplotlib. The tutorials for these libraries are great. Try them out, but if you're stuck somewhere, post a new question. To be honest, this sort of data is most efficiently represented as a dictionary instead of nested lists. That way, you can easily access these items just using their names like "Calcium Plus" etc.

Answer (score 0):

If they're comma separated values, use the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

with open('chookfood.txt') as chookfood:
    rows = csv.reader(chookfood)
    for row in rows:
        print(row[1])
```

Comment: How would you call a specific value to print or use in a calculation. lets say the file values change but the format stays the same?

Comment: @Dylan see how to create a [mcve], search for an answer, and ask another question if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the initial list to store it in a dictionary:

```
def readfile():
    dictionary = { data[0]: [float(data[1], float(data[2])] for data in [line.split(',') for line in open("chookfood.txt", 'r')]
    print(dictionary)
```

You could access the first element of Mash by writing:

```
print(dictionary[“Mash”][0])
```

Comment: Lets say the text file changes but keeps the same style. So Mash gets changed to Grain. And the cost change. How do I call those values?

Comment: In that case the key of the dictionary has changed. You'd have to write `dictionary["Grain"][0]` instead of `dictionary["Mash"][0]`